# Add dynamic jquery data into appended html

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to put `calEvent.id` into `#id` in appended html?

```
$("#id").val(calEvent.id);
if(calEvent.status == 'open') {
    $('#append .appact').remove();
    $('#append').append("<div class='appact'><form id='update'><input type='hidden' name='id' id='id'><br/><input type='submit' name='submit'></form></div>");
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the ID of the hidden input to be `calEvent.id`?

Comment: Where do you want to put `#id` in appended html?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I need event id to be in hidden input field. id is inserted in input with #id when input is already in html but when I append it id is not inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you need this should work:

```
$("#id").val(calEvent.id);
if(calEvent.status == 'open') {
    $('#append .appact').remove();
    $('#append').append("<div class='appact'><form id='update'><input type='hidden' name='id' id='"+calEvent.id+"'><br/><input type='submit' name='submit'></form></div>");
}
```

Comment: i need id as value but this is it

Comment: @Yesian_ you can se id after appending the html as well

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#append').append(
    $("<div />", {
        'class': 'appact'
    }).append(
        $('<form />', {
            id: 'update'
        }).append(
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'hidden',
                name: 'id',
                id: 'id',
                value: calEvent.id    // Notice here
            }),
            $('<input />', {
                type: 'submit',
                name: 'submit'
            })
        )
    )
);
```